# How can I customise your's MBCalendarKit?

Tags: calendar, customization, mbcalendarkit

Great tool you provided us!

I loved the table below the calendar. It's reeeeeealy useful.
The only issue I'm having is to customize the calendar view...
I needed something cleaner. Do you have tips where I can start looking for customising the view?

I looking for something like this: https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar/blob/master/Screens/example.gif

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [`CKCalendarCell`](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/MBCalendarKit/CalendarKit/Core/CKCalendarCell.m) and [`CKCalendarHeaderView`](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/MBCalendarKit/CalendarKit/Core/CKCalendarHeaderView.m)classes.

The look and feel of the cells and the header are in there.

CKCalendarCell uses the concept of states to determine what gets rendered when. There are seven states:

```
CKCalendarMonthCellStateTodaySelected = 0,      //  Today's cell, selected
CKCalendarMonthCellStateTodayDeselected = 1,    //  Today's cell, unselected
CKCalendarMonthCellStateNormal,                 //  Cells that are part of this month, unselected
CKCalendarMonthCellStateSelected,               //  Cells that are part of this month, selected
CKCalendarMonthCellStateInactive,               //  Cells that are not part of this month
CKCalendarMonthCellStateInactiveSelected,       //  Transient state for out of month cells
CKCalendarMonthCellStateOutOfRange              //  A state for cells that are bounded my min/max constraints on the calendar picker
```

The state of each cell is determined based on if it's part of the current month or not, if the cell is selected, and if the cell has an active touch in it.

Have a look at the `applyColorsForState:` method for the coloring and stuff. You may want to add your own `borderRadius` and `clipsToBounds` values.

The colors for the header are defined in [`CKCalendarHeaderColors.h`](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/MBCalendarKit/CalendarKit/Headers/CKCalendarHeaderColors.h) as hex values, which are converted to UIColors with a category on NSString.